# How can I get my index.html file moved into my /dist/ folder in Webpack?

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack

I currently have my directories setup such that my whole React project, including `index.html`, is inside my `src/` directory. When I run `npm run build`, all of my `.js/css` files are put into my `/dist` folder. However, my `index.html` isn't being included. I installed `html-loader` and set it up in my `webpack.config.js` as such:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    include: APP_DIR, //let APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')//
    loader: 'html-loader'
  }
```

My understanding was that this would add my `index.html` file into my `dist/` after running a build but it's not. I've looked at the `html-webpack-plugin` but what I gather from that is that it generates an `index.html` file for you but I don't need one generated for me. I just want to include the one I already created.

Comment: Well, the index.html file is probably no where imported in your code. You should rather go for a copy from your source file to the target location

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I did need the `html-webpack-plugin` and just needed to add the option for a template, which would be my own `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

I later realized that the `html-webpack-plugin` allows for a template option which, in my case, would be my own `src/index.html` file. It just copies it over into the `index.html` it generates in my `dist/` folder.